# JSONSerialization with optionals in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

In Swift 3, `JSONSerialization` of arrays with optional values fails.
<s>This worked in Swift 2 (yielding null as the JSON value of `nil` optionals as would be expected).</s>

**Edit:** It didn't, but leaving it here as this was my incorrect belief when asking the question.

Swift 2:

```
let a: [String!] = ["a","b","c"]
let b: [String] = ["a","b","c"]

let s: String! = "a"
let c = ["a",s]

NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(a)    //true
NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(b)    //true
NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(c)    //true
```

Swift 3:

```
let a: [String?] = ["a","b","c"]
let b: [String] = ["a","b","c"]

let s: String! = "a"
let c = ["a",s]

JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(a)    //false
JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(b)    //true
JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(c)    //false
```

Is this an intended change?
It seems quite error prone as any arrays or dictionaries constructed with an implicit type now potentially are not valid for JSON (even if they do not actually contain any nil values).

Additionally, how can null values then be specified?

Comment: How did this work in Swift 2? `NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(a)` does not even *compile.*

Comment: I don't know if isvalidJSONObject specifically returned true in swift 2, but NSJSONSerialization was happy to serialize dictionaries or arrays containing optionals (a cast may be needed but they could be defined just as above)

Comment: I don't think so, `let d = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(a, options: [])` does not compile with Swift 2. Can you provide an example with optionals that compiles with Swift 2 but not with Swift 3?

Comment: What is the expected result of serializing an array of optional strings?

Comment: `NSNull()` is serialized to "null", but optionals are not automatically converted to "null". What changed is the treatment of implicitly unwrapped optionals, but makes a difference only for your `c`, not for `a`.

Comment: Edited to provide a swift 2 example. Just to clarify, the issue is not compilation but the ability to serialize.

Comment: @vadian - the expected result would be that optional strings with values serialize to that value, and optional strings with are nil serialize to null (valid according to the json spec http://www.json.org/

Comment: @davedavedave: Your Swift 2 code uses *implicitly unwrapped optionals,* and `a` serializes to `["a","b","c"]`. If you change it to `let a: [String!] = ["a",nil,"c"]` then it crashes. If you change it to `let a: [String?] = ["a",nil,"c"]` then it does not compile anymore. – So there is no conversion of `nil` to "null" in Swift 2.

Comment: @davedavedave: Your Swift 2 example does not contain any real optional (`?`) so I doubt that the code worked as expected. The behavior of implicit unwrapped optionals is indeed different in Swift 2 and 3.

Comment: It's not the difference of the ability to serialize, but the ability of bridging. As you know, `NSJSONSerialization` (or `JSONSerialization`) uses `NSArray` (or `NSDictionary`) internally, but Swift 3 cannot **safely** bridge Array of Optional type to `NSArray`.

Comment: @MartinR you're quite right, it seems I was confused about this working in swift 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @OOPer: That changed with Xcode 8.1 beta :)

Comment: @MartinR, I know. When the release version of Xcode 8.1 is out, I will update my answers related to SE-0139 and SE-0140.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** As of **Swift 3.0.1/Xcode 8.1 beta 2,** optionals
are bridged to `NSNull` instances automatically, see

- [SE-0140  – Warn when Optional converts to Any, and bridge Optional As Its Payload Or NSNull](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md)

and the Xcode 8.1 beta release notes.

Example:

```
let array: [String?] = [ "a", nil, "c"]
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array)

print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!)
// ["a",null,"c"]
```

---

*Previous answer for Swift 2 and 3.0:* Only `NSNull()` is serialized to JSON **null**, not optionals
(independent of the Swift version).

An array of optionals could be transformed like this:

```
let a: [String?] = ["a", nil, "c"]

let b = a.map { $0 as Any? ?? NSNull() }
print(b) // ["a", <null>, "c"]

let d = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: b)
print(String(data: d, encoding: .utf8)!) // ["a",null,"c"]
```