# Comparing non-optional Any to nil is always false?

Tags: swift

I'm iterating through a dictionary of `[String: Any]`, looking for `nil`s, so I can replace them with `NSNull` for a JSON write. My precompiler warning is telling me that comparing an `Any` to a `nil` will always be false, but I know it contains at least two nils which are never found. Is there a way to check is an `Any` is nil?

Comment: As of Swift 3.0.1 (Xcode 8.1), `nil` is automatically bridged to `NSNull` when passed to an Objective-C API (and becomes **null** in the JSON), see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md. That might make your check redundant, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39976821/1187415 for an example.

Comment: I think this will solve it - I'm on 8.0 now, whenever I try writing a nil to JSON it gives me an error for invalid type SwiftValue

Answer (score 14):

An Optional can be `nil`. Anything else can never be `nil`. An `Any` is not an Optional. Thus there is no point comparing an `Any` to `nil`. The test will never succeed.

If you know that these things might be Optionals, you should have typed this as `Any?`. That is an Optional and can be compared to `nil`. Here's a simple example:

```
    let s : String? = nil
    let any : Any? = s
    if any == nil {
        print("nil") // nil
    }
```

As you can see, the test succeeds.

(Still, if at all possible, it would be even better to type things more precisely.)

Comment: Maybe my unwrapping is off, but trying this didn't give me any help -             
```
for (_, attr) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
                if let propName = attr.label, let jsonKey = keys[propName] {
                    if let nilable = attr.value as Any? {
                        if nilable == nil {
                            print("never called")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well, if you want to get into specifics of your code you'd need to ask another question, in which you show that code and everything needed to understand it (i.e. the declared types of everything). I answered only and exactly the question you _actually asked_, i.e. why you are getting this warning and runtime result, and what it would take to get a successful comparison to `nil`.

Comment: possibly irrelevant to the current case, but it's pretty easy to construct a pointer to a nil in Objective-C that's non-optional in Swift. In my case this line

`[self viewWillTransitionToSize:self.view.bounds.size withTransitionCoordinator:self.transitionCoordinator];`

is passing nil for tx coordinator which is non-optional in Swift. I'm not suggesting this is great code, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @DanRosenstark I'm confused by what that means. `viewWillTransitionToSize` is not something you call; it is something that the runtime calls on you. And when it does, the transition coordinator will _not_ be nil. So Swift's characterization is correct. Moreover, no Any is involved here so this doesn't seem relevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: Calling the method yourself is obviously an anti-pattern, but it's an example of how to pass a nil to a non-optional. It's relevant only in that it's a non-optional getting passed a nil.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this using bellow expression:

```
let filteredResult = dictionary.filter { !(($0.value as AnyObject) is NSNull) }
```

Answer (score 3):

`if(object_getClass(yourVariable)?.description() == "NSNull")` 
can be one of the way to check.

Comment: Thanks.
It solved my problem. There are some bugs and problems on Optional types and generics.
You can see my code: https://gist.github.com/fthdgn/12e62c1002fe9c9695fff780ffb91994#file-genericnilcheckerror-swift-L7

Answer (score 1):

Objective-c property in swift.
If you're using some objective c property in swift  and it says something like **"Comparing    non-optional value of type 'XYZ' to 'nil' always returns true"** you have to make that objective c property to **"_Nullable"** so that    property may not be optional anymore. Like
`@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *_Nullable someString;`